# How to add KVO for UINavigationBar hidden/unhidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add an observer for `UINavigationBar` hidden/unhidden like the following code, but it does not work anyway:

`[self.navigationController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"navigationBarHidden" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];`

and also tried this,still not work:

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"hidden" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];`

when I check the `self.navigationController.navigationBar` in LLDB,it told me property `navigationController not found for UIViewController` (means `self`). Does anyone have the same problem?

addtional message:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"hidden" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

}

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"hidden"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"hidden"]) {
        NSLog(@"navigation bar is hidden/unhidden");
    }
}
```

I tried for navigationBarHidden and hidden both.

Comment: Show more code, including `@implementation` and `@end` lines. What's the output of `NSLog(@"Class: %@", NSStringFromClass(self.class));`?

Comment: @alejandro-iván the log code you mentioned, `self.class` is a kind of `UIViewController`

Comment: Again, add more code... specifically the methods from where you're sending those messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVO operates only on properties that are set using KVC. UINavigationController has no KVC-compliant property pertaining to the showing and hiding of its navigation bar. Therefore you cannot use KVO to detect when the navigation bar is shown and hidden.

Comment: thx a lot, is there anyway to detect the UINavigationBar hidden/unhidden

Comment: @DanielWang maybe trying with the change of `frame` or `bounds`?

Comment: My first question would be, how can you not _know_ whether the navigation bar is hidden or not? Why do you need to _detect_ it? It doesn't just magically go away, after all.

Comment: @matt I inherit a UIViewController write by someone else(by cocoapods), for some reason, I have to custom the view and what i want to add should hidden/unhidden follow the UINavigationBar. Since I can't rewrite  the private methods of the super class,so I want to figure out when the UINavigationBar hidden/unhidden

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. It seems not possible to get the status via KVO. I am trying to add a timer that checks the navigation bar is hidden or not every 0.5 seconds. It is a little bit tricky, but at least it works.